# Excel VBA: Need Workaround for 255 Transpose Character Limit When Returning Variant Array to Selected Range

Tags: vba, function, excel, character-limit

I am struggling with a common problem involving an apparent Excel 255-character-limit. I encounter an error when attempting to return a variant-array from a Function to the selected range on the worksheet. **When each of the cells in the Function's returning array are under 255 characters, they post to the sheet just as they should: one element appears in each cell within the selected range. However, if any element in my returning variant array is longer than 255 characters I get a Value! error.** These errors are bad because I need my long elements and want to keep the data together!

**Versions of this problem appear over and over again in many forums,  yet I am able to find a clear simple, all-purpose solution for returning variant arrays to the selected range (not necessarily containing formulas) when the array cells exceed 255 characters.** My largest elements are around 1000, but it would be better if the solution could accommodate elements up to 2000 characters.

Preferably, I want this to be implemented with a function, or lines of additional code which can be added to my function **(not a subroutine)**. My reason for wanting to avoid subroutines: I do not want to have to hard-code any ranges. I want this to be flexible and for the output location to be dynamically based on my current selection.

**Please, if you can help find a way to produce a function, which takes a Variant Array as input, and which maintains the desired array:cell 1:1 relationship, I'd appreciate it greatly.**

So this function with short cells works:

```
Function WriteUnder255Cells()

Dim myArray(3) As Variant  'this the variant array I will attempt to write

' Here I fill each element with less than 255 characters
' it should output them if you call the function properly.
myArray(0) = "dog"
myArray(1) = "cat"
myArray(2) = "bird"
myArray(3) = "fly"

WriteUnder255Cells = Application.Transpose(myArray())

End Function
```

But this fuction, with cells exceeding 255 will not output.

```
Function WriteOver255Cells()

Dim myArray(3) As Variant  'this the variant array I will attempt to write

' Here I fill each element with more than 255 characters
' exceeding the 255-character limit causes the VALUE! errors when you output them
myArray(0) = "ThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelaxydog"
myArray(1) = "ThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog"
myArray(2) = "ThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog"
myArray(3) = "ThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogThequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog"

WriteOver255Cells = Application.Transpose(myArray())

End Function
```

This is how you produce the output and results:

First you need to create the two modules(to insert one function into each module,  paste the code from one into the respective module). To run  "WriteUnder255Cells()", select an area of 4 rows x 1 column on the sheet (this where you return the module) and type  "=WriteUnder255Cells()" into the formula bar (do not enter the quotes).  Note these are called like array formulas, so instead of hitting (enter) to create the output, **you need to hit (control + shift + enter)**. Repeat the same process for WriteOver255Cells() to produce the errors.

Here are some documents/forums discussions which address it. The solutions seem to be either overly specific or clunky because they evoke subroutines (which I want to avoid):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213841

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/852781-visual-basic-applications-evaluate-method-255-character-limit.html

[Excel: Use formula longer that 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386414/excel-use-formula-longer-that-255-characters)

[VBA code error when array value exceeds 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999740/vba-code-error-when-array-value-exceeds-255-characters)

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/

https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-vba-access-to-excel-255-char-limit-issue.996495/

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/494675-255-character-cell-limit-visual-basic-applications-workaround.html

[Array formula with more than 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949221/array-formula-with-more-than-255-characters)

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/388250-size-limit-transferring-variant-range-excel-2007-a.html

Comment: Nice collection of links. Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Good point, I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Function Over255()

    Dim myArray(3)  As String '<<<<< not variant

    myArray(0) = String(300, "a")
    myArray(1) = String(300, "b")
    myArray(2) = String(300, "c")
    myArray(3) = String(300, "d")

    'Over255 = Application.Transpose(myArray())
    Over255 = TR(myArray)

End Function

'like Application.Transpose...
Function TR(arrIn) As String()
    Dim arrOut() As String, r As Long, ln As Long, i As Long

    ln = (UBound(arrIn) - LBound(arrIn)) + 1
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ln, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    For r = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn)
        arrOut(i, 1) = arrIn(r)
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    TR = arrOut

End Function
```

Seems like you need to return a string array and `Application.Transpose` doesn't do that

Comment: Thank you!! That is a very clean and clear solution!!!!  It works wonderfully!!!!!!