# Issue with row combining macro deleting data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet of data that looks something like this:

```
V1 Wht
V1 blck
V1 Red 
V2 Wht
V2 Grn 
V3 prpl
```

and I need it to simplify down to

```
V1 wht, blck, red
V2 Wht, grn
V3 prpl
```

I found a Macro online that will do this

```
Sub CombineRows()
'Update 20131202
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = WorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    xvalue = arr(i, 1)
    If Dic.Exists(xvalue) Then
        Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) & ", " & arr(i, 2)
    Else
        Dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
WorkRng.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However it only works for small chunks of around 40 values or less. Anything more and the sub will paste the values for the keys in left column, however, the right column where the items should be, will be blank.

Is there any way to modify this code to be able to handle more data safely?

Thanks!

Comment: use dictionary....

Comment: @cyboashu, don't tell me you didn't look at the code part. ;)

Comment: `it destroys the data in the right column` pls explain.

Comment: You really don't need line `Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)` if you have already selected the range in Excel as `Set WorkRng = Application.Selection` will handle it.

Comment: @ManishChristian oh so dumb of me ;)

Comment: I also don't quite understand how the xvalue property works

Comment: @ManishChristian 
      
 
The sub will paste the values for the keys in left column, however, the right column where the items should be, is blank. It will work correctly when I only select a small number of rows but starts returning blank cells once the selection becomes too large. I'm guessing this is some sort of issue with the resizing?

Comment: How big range you are talking about...?

Comment: @ManishChristian It seems to be able to handle around 40 rows ok but anything over that and it stops working. Ideally, I need It to be able to handle around 3000 rows. I don't know if this is something that can be fixed with this sub or if I will have to write a new sub from scratch.

Comment: Is your data repetitive? I mean will `V1 Wht` come again? If yes than should the result be like `V1 Wht, blck, Red, Wht,...`?

Comment: @ManishChristian Tranpose  fails when the item value is >255.

Comment: @ManishChristian No, the key column (V1's) are all in order and do not repeat later in the list. The values in the Item column do repeat, but only for different v values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tranpose has a limit of 255 chars length. Anyhow in your code you dont need to transpose the data at all. Drop the transpose part and it works fine.

---

**Edit**: You do need to transpose the keys and values. There is a workaround for the limit. I have added that. Code copied from :https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399740/3961708

---

```
   Sub CombineRows()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Dic As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim arrItems
    Dim arrTest() As String
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arr = WorkRng.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        'xvalue = arr(i, 1)
        If Dic.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) & ", " & arr(i, 2)
        Else
            Dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WorkRng.ClearContents
    WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = TR(Dic.keys)

    '/* Check here. Transpose has a limit on 255 chars.
    arrItems = Dic.items
    arrTest = Application.Transpose(arrItems) '/ Put thi sin watch window and it will be blank if the value length is more than 255 chars.

    WorkRng.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = TR(arrItems)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

'/ Code copied from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399740/3961708
Function TR(arrIn) As String()
    Dim arrOut() As String, r As Long, ln As Long, i As Long

    ln = (UBound(arrIn) - LBound(arrIn)) + 1
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ln, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    For r = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn)
        arrOut(i, 1) = arrIn(r)
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    TR = arrOut

End Function
```

Comment: hmm... They do NEED to be TRANSPOSED.

Comment: @cyboashu Tried it with the work around and it works beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know @cyboashu have already answered, but could you please try this code to see if it's working with your large set of data:

```
Sub CombineRows()
    'Update 20131202
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Dic As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arr = WorkRng.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        xvalue = arr(i, 1)
        If Dic.Exists(xvalue) Then
            Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) & ", " & arr(i, 2)
        Else
            Dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WorkRng.ClearContents
    i = 1
    'Assuming your data is in column A and B
    For Each Value In Dic.Keys
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Value
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Dic(Value)
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```