# VBA: Cannot put Dictionary items into range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Dictionary to store data and then dump them into another sheet. Basically I have data of this format:

```
abc    12367

abe    23456

abe    34567

dfy    78890
```

And I need to output like this:

```
abc    12367

abe    23456, 34567

dfy    78890
```

Here is the code for storing and outputting the data:

```
Function ReadDict(ByVal wb_name As String, ByVal ws_name As String, row_begin As Integer, row_end As Integer, col As Integer) As Dictionary
On Error Resume Next

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim dictStorage As New Dictionary

Set wbSource = Workbooks(wb_name)
If wbSource Is Nothing Then
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(wb_name)
End If

Dim iRowCounter As Integer
Dim vKey, vItem As Variant

For iRowCounter = row_begin To row_end
    vKey = wbSource.Sheets(ws_name).Cells(iRowCounter, col).Value
    vItem = wbSource.Sheets(ws_name).Cells(iRowCounter, col + 1).Value

    If dictStorage.Exists(vKey) = False Then
        dictStorage.Add vKey, vItem
    Else
        dictStorage.item(vKey) = dictStorage.item(vKey) & ", " & vItem
    End If
Next iRowCounter

Set ReadDict = dictStorage
End Function
```

I'm pretty sure that this works because I can Debug.Print.

The write function:

```
Function WriteDict(ByVal wb_name As String, ByVal ws_name As String, row_begin As Integer, col As Integer, dict As Dictionary)
On Error Resume Next

If dict.Count <= 0 Then MsgBox ("Dictionary contains no item!")

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet

Set wbSource = Workbooks(wb_name)
If wbSource Is Nothing Then
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(wb_name)
End If

With Worksheets(ws_name)
    Dim ky As Variant
    With dict
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2 + .Count, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
        Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2 + .Count, 2)).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
    End With
End With

Set dict = Nothing
End Function
```

The function only writes the keys, but not the items. Why? I'm pretty the items are there, because I can simply Debug.Print them. And what's most frustrating is that the write function works fine if certain rows are not read, but I swear there is nothing special with those rows...

I'm listing the main sub:

```
Sub CombineTJ()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sSourceWB, sSourceWS, sTargetWS As String
Dim dictTJ As New Dictionary
sSourceWS = ActiveSheet.Name
sTargetWS = "Target"
sSourceWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = sTargetWS

Set dictTJ = ReadTJDict(sSourceWB, sSourceWS, 2, 8442, 1)

Call WriteTJDict(sSourceWB, sTargetWS, 2, 1, dictTJ)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure it works fine if ReadTJDict() does not read some rows between row 1950 and row 2000, but nothing is special is there.

Comment: _(As short-hand, I will be referring to the column in the sheet where the items should go, as the items-column.)_ Are you saying that the current (incorrect) output is that the items-column is blank, or that it is populated with the key values instead? I'm assuming that the code is'nt throwing any errors since you haven't mentioned any.

Comment: @Mistella Hi I found the reason, seems that one item of the dictionary has length more than 255 char and causes the problem. It's only showing the keys, not the items.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395789/excel-vba-need-workaround-for-255-transpose-character-limit-when-returning-vari

Answer (score 0):

OK folks, I have identified the problem. I have one key that has a very long item (more than 255 characters). I'm pretty sure that:

1. Excel cell can hold more than 255 char
2. Excel dictionary can hold items that are longer than 255 char (because I can debug.print this item)

However, for some reason, because of this item, it breaks the code. I added a line to restrict the length and everything is fine now.

Comment: Suspect your problem is the use of `ApplicationTranpose`: if you skip that and use a loop to create your transposed array you can use whatever length you like.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395789/excel-vba-need-workaround-for-255-transpose-character-limit-when-returning-vari

Comment: @Tim Williams Hi the loop works however very slowly even disabled screen update

Comment: Are you creating an array and then assigning it to the range in one operation, or filling the range cell-by-cell?  An array-based approach should be no slower than your original method.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm creating a dictionary actually. I'll try arrays later, btw thanks for your post, I did not know that there is a 255-char limit on transpose.